# When I update an app in Play Store, does a text file reset his content?

Tags: android, text-files

I use a text file (saved in Assets) to save some information about the preferences of the user. But when I update the app with a newer version, does the text file reset?
Thanks.

Comment: How can you even save to assets, i thought they were read only.

Answer (score 3):

Assets reset after update apk. Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: Can you please give a reference?

Comment: Click on word 'SharedPreferences' above in my answer

Comment: Thanks, but I know about SharedPreferences, i've asked about the Assets not being reset by updates. Can you please elaborate or give a reference for that?

Comment: Please see assets's description on page https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/projects/index.html